# Getting value and href of closest anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value and href link of the closest anchor tag based on a nearby button. As you can see, this is a list of anchor tags and buttons. so want to target that specific anchor tag when clicking on a button. I am logging to see the name and href, but coming as empty and undefined. what am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input_fields_wrap').on("click",".addlink-edit-icon",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $('.show_field').closest('a');
        var edit_name = target.text();
        var edit_address = target.attr('href');
        console.log('name', edit_name );
        console.log('address', edit_address);
   
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="input_fields_wrap" style="overflow-y: hidden;">

    <div class="addlink_dynlist">
      <li>
        <a href="aaaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaa</a>
        <span class="show_field">
                 <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>

        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="bbbb">bbbbbbbbbb</a>
        <span class="show_field">
                 <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>

        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="ccc">cccccccccc</a>
        <span class="show_field">
                 <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>

        </span>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./js/test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you not able to use `.closest()` for your situation? https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: I think you misunderstand [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). It gets the closest ancestor. That's what you'd use to get the `show_field` element (e.g., `$(this).closest('.show_field')`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `closest` finds the closest ancestor/parent element using a specific selector rather than a sibling.

***In that markup the link that you want to select is not an ancestor/parent of the buttons.***

**Further, this line must be modified:**

```
var target = $('.show_field').closest('a');
```

**To this:**

```
               +---- This is the current clicked button.
               |
               |                         +--- Gets the desired element 'a'
               |                         |
               v                         v
var target = $(this).closest('li').find('a');
                              ^
                              |
                              +---- Finds the closest ancestor 'li'.
```

An alternative is to find the closest element `li` and then find an element `a`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input_fields_wrap').on("click", ".addlink-edit-icon", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).closest('li').find('a');
    var edit_name = target.text();
    var edit_address = target.attr('href');
    console.log('name', edit_name);
    console.log('address', edit_address);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="input_fields_wrap" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div class="addlink_dynlist">
      <li>
        <a href="aaaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaa</a>
        <span class="show_field">
             <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="bbbb">bbbbbbbbbb</a>
        <span class="show_field">
             <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="ccc">cccccccccc</a>
        <span class="show_field">
             <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>
        </span>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great thanks, understanding of the closest() was the issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to traverse up the DOM to the list item first, with `.closest('li')` and then down to the link using `.find('a')`. Essentially, just change:

```
var target = $('.show_field').closest('a');
```

to

```
var target = $(this).closest('li').find('a');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input_fields_wrap').on("click",".addlink-edit-icon",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).closest('li').find('a');
        var edit_name = target.text();
        var edit_address = target.attr('href');
        console.log('name', edit_name );
        console.log('address', edit_address);

    });
});
```

```html
<div class="input_fields_wrap" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
  <div class="addlink_dynlist">
    <li>
      <a href="aaaaaaaaaaaa">aaaaaaaa</a>
      <span class="show_field">
                 <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="bbbb">bbbbbbbbbb</a>
      <span class="show_field">
                 <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ccc">cccccccccc</a>
      <span class="show_field">
                 <button class="fa fa-pencil-square-o addlink-edit-icon hand-cursor">edit</button>
        </span>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```